# Finding row index of a row within the original datatable

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable that I fill with data

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
FillData(data);
```

The datatable gets modified on the go and I capture the modified data so I can save it in a DB:

```
DataTable changes = data.GetChanges();
```

I use data from the `changes` DataTable and save it into DB, the query I use returns an INT id that I need to save into the original `data` DataTable. How can I get corresponding index in the `data` table basig on the `changes` table?

Comment: Use the original `DataTable` to update the database? Why not?

Comment: I managed to solve it using the original DT and RowState, don't know why I didn't come up with that earlier. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used to intersect to get intersection of data table and changes table

```
    public void intersect(DataTable data, DataTable changes)
            {
                var changeIds = data.AsEnumerable().Intersect(changes.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default);


                foreach (DataRow row in changeIds)
                {
                    Response.Write(row["Id"]);
                }
            }
```